# Add images to JPanel one per line

Tags: java, swing

I want to add one image for each line in a JScrollPane with a JPanel inside. This is the approach I though of:

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayWithPaths.size();i++){
BufferedImage newPic;
try {
newPic = ImageIO.read(new File("path");
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(newPic));
panel.add(picLabel);
JLabel space = new JLabel("\n");
panel.add(space);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However this prints the pictures in just one line.

Comment: Can you indent your code sensibly please?

Comment: Please see edit to answer for example

Comment: why did you vote -1?

Comment: Not my down-vote, but you don't appear to have improved your code's formatting even though it was requested. It's generally expected that you post only well formatted code since it's hard enough to struggle to understand someone else's code, and you really don't want to make it harder than it needs to be.  Also we're all volunteers on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a completely different approach -- use a JList that is displayed within the JScrollPane, and add ImageIcons to your JList's model. The JList will know how to handle ImageIcons and will display your images. They're even selectable if need be.

And here's another example:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageList extends JPanel {
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "http://file.kelleybluebookimages.com/"
            + "kbb/images/content/editorial/";
    private static final String[] PATHS = {
        "2015-acura-tlx-guide-180.jpg",
        "13A420TFSI_01_hrgb-180.jpg",
        "CT_071713_BMW320i_0439-180.jpg",
        "2013-Cadillac-ATS-137-180.jpg",
        "EJ2V1342-180.jpg",
        "2014LexusIS005-180.jpg",
        "2014-volvo-s60-180.jpg",
        "2015-jeep-renegade-profile-180.jpg"
    };
    private DefaultListModel<Icon> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Icon> imageJList = new JList<>(listModel);

    public ImageList() throws IOException {
        for (String path : PATHS) {
            String imgPath = BASE_PATH + path;
            URL url = new URL(imgPath);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
            listModel.addElement(new ImageIcon(img));
        }

        imageJList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageJList);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scrollPane);
    }    

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageList");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            frame.getContentPane().add(new ImageList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @trashgod: and another example

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java Swing Layout Manager tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

You need to configure your `panel` object appropriately, using a `BoxLayout` for example may give you what you need.